# How to set spacing between each grid item in Material UI?

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

I want to set automatic spacing between content boxes. But if I add: Spacing, padding or margin properties. they will destroy my layout. Unlike using column-gap and row-gap properties in the default grid system. Please help me to solve this problem.

```js
        <Grid xs={12} sm={12} lg={10} container className={`${styles.Item} ${styles.Item3}`}>
          <Grid xs={12} sm={6} lg={4}>
            Content 1
          </Grid>
          <Grid xs={12} sm={6} lg={4}>
            Content 2
          </Grid>
          <Grid xs={12} sm={6} lg={4}>
            Content 3
          </Grid>
          <Grid xs={12} sm={6} lg={4}>
            Content 4
          </Grid>
          <Grid xs={12} sm={6} lg={4}>
            Content 5
          </Grid>
          <Grid xs={12} sm={6} lg={4}>
            Content 6
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

Before:
[image: Before:]

After adding rowSpacing={5}, columnSpacing={5}:
[image]

After adding margin property:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `spacing` property on a `<Grid>` being used as `container`.

To avoid any malfunction of `<Grid>`, you could choose not to add custom styling on them. Instead, put a custom `<Item>` component inside a `<Grid>`, and style the custom component, as shown in below example.

Hope this will help!

**Only for grid version 1**: An `item` property also need to be added on any `<Grid>` being used as grid items.

A quick example: (live demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-u8vtg6?file=src/App.js), **Updated to include grid version 2**)

```
import React from 'react';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Grid2 from '@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2'; // Grid version 2
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

const Item = styled(Box)({
  backgroundColor: '#1E90FF',
  color: '#fff',
  minHeight: '5em',
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Stack direction="column" alignItems="flex-start" spacing={3}>
      <h2>Grid version 1</h2>
      <Grid container xs={12} sm={12} lg={10} spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} lg={4}>
          <Item>Content 1</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} lg={4}>
          <Item>Content 2</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} lg={4}>
          <Item>Content 3</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} lg={4}>
          <Item>Content 4</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} lg={4}>
          <Item>Content 5</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} lg={4}>
          <Item>Content 6</Item>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <h2>Grid version 2</h2>
      <Grid2 container xs={12} sm={12} lg={10} spacing={3}>
        <Grid2 xs={12} sm={6} lg={4}>
          <Item>Content 1</Item>
        </Grid2>
        <Grid2 xs={12} sm={6} lg={4}>
          <Item>Content 2</Item>
        </Grid2>
        <Grid2 xs={12} sm={6} lg={4}>
          <Item>Content 3</Item>
        </Grid2>
        <Grid2 xs={12} sm={6} lg={4}>
          <Item>Content 4</Item>
        </Grid2>
        <Grid2 xs={12} sm={6} lg={4}>
          <Item>Content 5</Item>
        </Grid2>
        <Grid2 xs={12} sm={6} lg={4}>
          <Item>Content 6</Item>
        </Grid2>
      </Grid2>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you but Grid version 2 removed item property.
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid2/

Comment: @QuanPhung I see, I did not know about grid version 2 before, so this is a good learning for me. I have updated the code example to include grid version 2 as well. Thanks!